# How do I find if a string has only letters, numbers and underscore characters?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I want to check if my string has only letters, numbers or underscore in it.
I have this code

```js
const str = 'test'

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str.charAt(i) != /^(\w|_)+$/) {
    return false
  }
}
```

No matter what, it's always returning false although just introducing valid values.

Could anyone help?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to check this character-by-character to begin with, and not just for the whole string in one go?

Comment: remove all but letters, numbers and underscores, then compare `.length` with the original string, if its shorter then its false

Comment: Based on the code in your question (I provided a snippet) you should be getting an error.

Comment: @Andy it's a part of a bigger file, I just put the part where I was struggling. With the solution that Tim provided below works as expected.

Comment: @CBroe I just didn't know about test() existence so I thought I had to check character by character

Comment: In ASCII?  It's not too hard, there's only 52 letters.  But for either UTF-8 or Unicode, it is a huge amount of work because there are thousands of letters (and alternative numbers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `test()` with the regex pattern `^\w+`:

```js
var str = 'test_here_123';
if (/^\w+$/.test(str)) {
    console.log("only letters, numbers, or underscore");
}
```

For reference, `\w` by definition matches letters, numbers, or underscore (which are collectively known as "word characters").

Comment: Wow, quite simple and working right. Many thanks Tim!!